# Construct a discontinuous solution of a given autonomous differential equation from a continuous one

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given an autonomous differential equation $dy/dx$= $f(y)$. we have a continuous solution say some $y=f(t)$, can I construct a discontinuous solution to the differential equation by doing the following:

I simply cut the continuous solution into finite number of segments, then I permute the order of such segments horizontally over t. since the DE is autonomous, we still retain the same gradient given y, but changing their relative positions over t.

Is this a valid construction of a discontinuous solution? Do I run into problems at the cutting points, since they are not differentiable at these cutting points?

Comment: As you point out, a discontinuous function is not differentiable at the points of discontinuity (differentiable implies continuous).  So the functions you are trying to build will not truly be solutions of the differential equation, unless you restrict their domain to avoid discontinuities (which seems to vitiate the purpose of your construction).

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a solution of an ODE satisfies the given ODE at all points in its domain. Therefore it is differentiable, hence continuous, in its domain. There is no such thing as a "discontinuous solution" of an ODE.

Assume that $f$ satisfies the assumptions of the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODE's.

If $f(y_0)=0$ then $y(t):\equiv y_0$ is a solution. Between two zeros $y_0$ and $y_1$ of $f$ the right side $y\mapsto f(y)$ does not change sign. It follows that for any initial point $(t_*,y_*)$ with $y_0<y_*<y_1$ the solution of the IVP
$$y'=f(y),\qquad y(t_*)=y_*$$
is monotonic and satisfies $y_0<y(t)<y_1$ for all $t$ in the domain of $y(\cdot)$. The cutting procedure you are describing can therefore not lead to a continuous function.

If, e.g., the function $f$ is given by $f(y):=3|y|^{2/3}$ then your cutting procedure, applied at $y=0$, produces new solutions.